# Refresh all contexts on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4

I have a WPF application where I have two windows. One is for **listing** objects (e.g. Books) and the other one is a form for **editing** one object (e.g. a Book). I create a new EF context for each of the windows.

Now I wonder, is there a way I can detect in the **list** window that a context has been edited after I call `SaveChanges` in the **edit** window?

What I do at the moment is to have a public `Update` method on my **list** window object that I call from the **edit** window after `SaveChanges` is called and in that function I call for the context refresh. However that is not scalable as I would need to keep track of all the windows that depend on Book information (e.g. if I add Shelves list I would need to make sure to update that one as well).

Any suggestions on how to solve this in more modular fashion?

P.S.
The funny part is that I seemed to have had an idea of how to improve this 2 years ago when I first wrote this code as I made a comment for myself: "TODO: solve this differently by having events in ArTresorEntities". But I don't remember what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **MVMM Light** you can send Message. Your List Window registers receiving message and latter notifies it about change. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your model class and then binding the value to your label/interface control.

Here's an example model class:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int random;

    public int Random
    {
        get { return random;  }
        set { random = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Random"); }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

That's all that's needed to implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged.  Notice that you have to call NotifyPropertyChanged during the set method of the property, otherwise this won't work.

```
On the UI side, you would do something like this:

<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Random, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Width="100" Height="40" Content="Randomize" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And then lastly, the code-behind for the xaml:

```
    public Data data;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new Data();
        this.DataContext = data;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        data.Random = new Random().Next(1000);
    }
```

The DataContext being assigned is just an example, but it binds this particular class to this window's dataContext, allowing me to do the {Binding Random} and know which property I'm talking about and in which class. You can do this in a few ways and split it up throughout a view.

I also added a button that generates a random number and sets it in my Random property on my model.  If you run this code, it updates the label each time you click the button.

Comment: Hm, that means I need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged` for every single property, right? Also, doesn't the setter get triggered before SaveChanges? Finally, I think this wouldn't handle the case when a new item (Book) is created.